# Why eclipse not detect java 14+ changes.?

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle, cxf

I'm running java project which is using CXF. Eclipse version: 2022-09 (4.25.0). Gradle used as a build tool and using gradle-7.3 version. OpenJDK set to the build path and it is openjdk-17.0.1, also compiler
in gradle file, tried with sourceCompatibility = 14 and latest versions.

It is not detecting below Java features.

- record

  `private record CommercialAgreement(Set<Long> agreementIds, Double value) {}`
- diamond operator <> (without types)

  `List<Shop> shops = getShopsList(ids, new TypeToken<>() {});`
- arrow in case statement & with return statements & multi constants case labels

  ```
  return switch (date) {
      case 1, 2 -> format(input, begin);
      case 3, 4, 5 -> format(input, mid);
      case 6, 7 -> format(input, end);
      default -> input;
  };
  ```

Are they known bugs or do we need to get some specific eclipse version to avoid these issues?

[image: Eclipse compiler tab]

[image: Gradle configs tab]

More screenshots added

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Please find the updated gradle build file here >>
https://notepad.link/share/O310KvZsEhGICCOhOazM

Comment: No, eclipse has known support for this stuff. Most likely culprit: Eclipse thinks the project's 'release' level is lower than 14. Gradle is technically turing complete so presumably if you change the gradle build file you need to tell either gradle or eclipse to reload a few things or it's not going to be able to pick up the change to sourceCompat. Also, 'sourceCompatibility' is old style - the modern way is to combine source and target into 'release'. A full answer to this question should probably include more details about how to properly set up the gradle build - I'm not familiar enough.

Comment: Eclipse knows about all these things and everything up to Java 18 (Java 19 in Eclipse 2022-12 released tomorrow). Check the project Java properties to see what compliance level you have set.

Comment: compiler screenshot attached, as you suggested I'll try 2022-12 eclipse version as well

Comment: Eclipse 2022-09 supports Java 17, Java 18 and lower. How to reproduce your issue? Where is your issue: in the Java editor (project settings looks fine, but disabling _Use default compliance settings_ does not make sense here), running Gradle (Gradle preferences looks fine, but might be overridden by the Gradle run configuration) or when running your application (show your launch configuration).

Comment: @howlger more screenshots added, thanks

Comment: Your `build.gradle` seems to be wrong. `sourceCompatibility = 1.8` means Java 8 which does not have those language features of Java 17 you are using. There should no `eclipse { ... }` section at all in your `build.gradle`.

Comment: @howlger thanks for your input, I've applied 17 instead of 1.8 but the issue still same

Comment: According to your screenshot you still have `sourceCompatibility = 1.8` which is clearly wrong. Your `build.gradle` should not have an `eclipse { ... } section` at all! Please show your [minimal `build.gradle` with which your issue can be reproduced](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @howlger, Please find the attached build gradle file. thanks
https://notepad.link/share/O310KvZsEhGICCOhOazM

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Again, the whole `eclipse { ... }` section looks quite suspicious.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251835/discussion-between-priyanwl2022-and-howlger).

Comment: @howlger
Please refer to the attached example >> https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vMPYPSFuxOuqi_i-v4_l7OAsOMyfLcGC/view?usp=sharing
hope it helps you to reproduce the issue. Thank you so much.!

Comment: @howlger, I've shared Minimal, Reproducible Example via above link. is it helpful for you.?

Comment: 11 MB is far from being minimal. According to the screenshots, you have `sourceCompatibility = 1.8` which is wrong and I doubt inside `eclipse { ... }` is the right place.

Comment: @howlger, sorry that is because of the hidden .git folder, I've removed that one.
now its almost 10KB

Comment: @howlger, have you got any clue from the example.? - thanks

Comment: With a `build.gradle` file in `service/Service` that contains the three lines `plugins { id 'application' }`, `sourceCompatibility = '17'` and `targetCompatibility = '17'` it works for me (imported via _File > Import...: Grade > Existing Gradle Project_ and fixing the broken Java example code, e.g. `switch (type)` where `type` is a String does not work with cases of enum types, etc.). It's recommended (and maybe required by Eclipse) to have `build.gradle` file in each Gradle project. Settings outside the project (to avoid redundancy), are hard to read and against self-contained modules.

Comment: `eclipse { jdt { sourceCompatibility = 17 } }` sets the source compatibility, but not the target compatibility and misses also to set the system library on the Java Build Path. You should have `sourceCompatibility = 17` and `targetCompatibility = 17` outside of `eclipse { ... }` in a `build.gradle` file instead.

Comment: @howlger thanks a lot for your inputs. its really means a lot to me. seems lot of faults in my side even importing project part (previously I did using import git-project). Thanks again I'll fix the issues based on your advises. Have a nice day.!

Answer (score 0):

This is not a solution but an alternative way, 
we can used when we need to fix build issues in gradle + eclipse + java.

I've tried and resolved in a following way.

1. `./gradlew eclipse` and make project to eclipse type project
2. `./gradlew clean install`
3. import project to eclipse
4. get all libraries from
   `<projectName>\build\install\<projectName>\lib\`
5. apply them to build-path manually
6. run the project